# Can WxFrame object be a part of another class inherited from wxWizardPageSimple in wxWizard?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have written code for `MyFrame`. I want `MyFrame` **CONTENTS** to be part of `MyPageInWizard1` in wxWizard. Is there any way that I can create an object of `MyFrame` and use it in the `MyPageInWizard1` of `wxWizard`? Or I have to copy code of `MyFrame` in that page?

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style) : wxFrame(parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
```

I am doing this: but that MyFrame contents are not displayed.

```
MyPageInWizard1::MyPageInWizard1(wxWizard *parent, wxWizardPage *prev, wxWizardPage *next)MyWizardPage(1, parent, prev, next)
{
SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255));

wxBoxSizer* bSizer3;
bSizer3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
MyHeading = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Some Heading"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
MyHeading->Wrap(-1);
MyHeading->SetFont(wxFont(14, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_BOLD, false, wxT("Arial")));

bSizer3->Add(MyHeading, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxALL, 5);
frame = new MyFrame(NULL);
bSizer3->Add(frame, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxALL, 5);
this->SetSizer(bSizer3);
}
```

Comment: try calling `frame = new MyFrame( this );`. But in general - why do you want to do that? It will be very weird design. You can try creating a public function inside the MyFrame class and call this function inside the wizard as well. This will be better. Or even better - get rid of the `MyFrame` class completely and just use a wizard.

Answer (score 0):

`wxFrame` is always a top level window, meaning that you can't put it inside any other window, including `wxWizard`.

To do what you want, you need to refactor your code and put the frame contents in some new `MyPanel` class deriving from `wxPanel`. Then your frame would contain just a `MyPanel` and you could also create (another) `MyPanel` inside the wizard.